# Port xxx is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port

Tags: angular6

On Windows, angular 6:
I tried use many port but no any port work. I always receive error message: **Port xxx is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port.**

I also researched and tried many ways: 
- turn of firewall
- using netstat to view ports and no any process use them
- change other version of angular-cli, typescript in package.json
But no solution for this.

This is my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-redux/store": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@mdi/font": "^3.6.95",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.2",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.14.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "adal-angular4": "^4.0.9",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "d3": "^5.9.2",
    "daterangepicker": "^3.0.5",
    "fabric": "^3.1.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "highcharts": "^6.1.4",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "msal": "^1.0.1",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ngrx-message-bus": "^1.0.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.1.2",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^8.0.1",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^1.3.9",
    "ngx-moment": "^3.4.0",
    "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^1.1.5",
    "ngx-toastr": "^9.1.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "tassign": "^1.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/d3": "^5.7.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.1.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.6",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

> PS E:\FSoft\source\Sample\App.Client> ng serve
>
> Port 4200 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port.
>
> PS E:\FSoft\source\Sample\App.Client> ng serve --port 4201
>
> Port 4201 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port.
>
> PS E:\FSoft\source\Sample\App.Client> ng serve --port 4216
>
> Port 4216 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port.
>
> PS E:\FSoft\source\Sample\App.Client> ng serve --port 4305
>
> Port 4305 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port.
>
> PS E:\FSoft\source\Sample\App.Client> ng serve --port 1234
>
> Port 1234 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port.
>
> PS E:\FSoft\source\Sample\App.Client> ng serve --port 9999
>
> Port 9999 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port.

Comment: Could be many reasons, is this your own personal laptop/PC? Could be a security issue with the company if it's not. Or your port are blocked by some kind of virus. There are too many possibilities.

Comment: I open a other project and it works normally. I think the problem in dependency of package.json. But I still can't find out.

Comment: I run this project in a new computer and it works ok. What can I do with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. This is my solution:

- Remove **node_modules**, include **package-lock.json**
- Run **npm i**, then I faced this error:

  > ERROR in node_modules/@angular-redux/store/lib/src/components/ng-redux.d.ts(10,31): error > TS2420: Class 'NgRedux' incorrectly implements interface
  >   'ObservableStore'.
  >    Property '[Symbol.observable]' is missing in type 'NgRedux'.
- I reinstall redux@4.0.1 by command: ***npm i redux@4.0.1***
- After finish, I start **ng serve**. It works OK.

Thanks for your attention.